# .NET MAUI Blazor how to change HostPage location

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

I'm attempting to place the Blazor website into a separate directory within the MAUI application to create separation (and in future use it as a GIT submodule).

But I don't seem to be able get MAUI to recognize a different BlazorWebView 'HostPage' reference than the default of wwwroot/index.html, does anyone know how to set this to this subdirectory location?

[image: Directory structure of Blazor site within MAUI application]

Current code for MainPage.xaml, it compiles and runs but gives 0.0.0.0 can't be found;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.ImagineItsASubModule"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
    <BlazorWebView HostPage="ImagineItsASubModule/wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue, posting here for any future people having issues.

Due to copying/importing the html/css etc the 'Build Action' on the files are set to 'None' so when build happened they naturally didn't come with the compile.

In order to do this I added the item group to my csproj file;

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="ImagineItsASubModule\\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now the files required come across and Blazor starts as expected, might need to mess with the regex to make sure that certain items are included/excluded as required.